# the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime

Tags: rust

```rust
trait X {}

trait Y {}

struct A {}

impl X for A {}

struct B<'r> {
    x: &'r mut Box<dyn X + 'r>,
    id: i32,
}

impl <'r> Y for B<'r> {}


struct Out {
    x: Box<dyn X>,
}

impl Out {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        return Out {
            x: Box::new(A{})
        }
    }

    pub fn get_data(&mut self) -> Box<dyn Y> {
        return Box::new(B{
            id: 1,
            x: &mut self.x
        })
    }
}
```

Run it [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=89dd18dcdd6acca4397b30b2a9a591f3) on playground.

I am getting this note from the compiler:

```
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
   = note: ...so that the expression is assignable:
           expected &mut std::boxed::Box<dyn X>
              found &mut std::boxed::Box<(dyn X + 'static)>
```

I understand where static lifetime is coming from, but doesn't the same lifetime is passed to struct B during its creation which accepts any generic lifetime.

[Edit After below answer]

I also tried making struct Out generic but then was unable to use it after initialization.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b19031cf8bd664c3d237a9bc27136936)). Here's the relevant code:

```
// note the lifetime!
struct Out<'a> {
    x: Box<dyn X + 'a>,
}

// note the lifetime!
impl<'a> Out<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        return Out {
            x: Box::new(A{})
        }
    }

    pub fn get_data(&'a mut self) -> Box<dyn Y + 'a> {
        return Box::new(B {
            id: 1,
            x: &mut self.x,
        })
    }
}
```

**Why is this necessary?**

Trait objects always have a lifetime. If no lifetime is specified or inferred, it defaults to `'static`. Therefore you have to make `Out` generic over its lifetime and use it in the implementation.

Comment: I thought of this, but then when trying to use the struct Out, I am getting `borrowed value does not live long enough`. Updated the playground with usage. Thanks

Comment: I can't see any changes. I think you created a new playground link and still have to update the question to insert the new link.

Comment: Yes, for now updated link is https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5b8039b27c003edd63c1e7e730af3d3d

Comment: I couldn't fix it, and I'm not entirely sure why it happens either. It might even be a compiler bug. You could ask on Reddit (/r/rust) or on users.rust-lang.org. On these forums, there are people with more experience with such issues than me.